# Evaluating $\int_0^{\sqrt 3} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \sin^{-1} (\frac{2x}{1+x^2}) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is to evaluate $$\int_0^{\sqrt 3}  \frac{1}{1+x^2} \sin^{-1} (\frac{2x}{1+x^2}) dx$$

I used the substitution $x=\tan a$ and it led me to the answer $\pi^2 /9$.However the correct answer is $\frac{7 \pi^2}{72}$.I couldn't get why the substitution is leading to a wrong answer.Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x=\tan y\implies0\le y\le\dfrac\pi3$

Using Principal [values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)

$$\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)=\sin^{-1}(\sin2y)=\begin{cases}2y&\mbox{if }0\le2y\le\dfrac\pi2 \\ 
\pi-2y & \mbox{if } \dfrac\pi2 \le2y\le\pi \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks I got it

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with using this substitution, and we cannot tell
where your calculation goes wrong unless you show your workings.

But consider this. If $x=\tan a$ then
$$\frac{2x}{1+x^2}=2\sin a\cos a=\sin 2a.$$
It may be tempting to write
$$\sin^{-1}(\sin 2a)=2a$$
but this may not be so. If $x=\sqrt3$, then $a=\pi/3$, $\sin(2a)=\sqrt3/2$
and $\sin^{-1}(\sqrt3/2)=\pi/3\ne 2a$.